# Check email and password from custom database tables in django

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-login

I am creating a website for my college where a student can register and login , the data will be stored in my custom table 'studentlogin'.

I am already collecting and storing user data in my database table but now I am stuck on how to compare this data to check if the email and password is correct or not

I found this solution from somewhere

```
add "django.core.context_processors.request" in your context processors in settings.py

def loginView(request):
# after checking if the user is active, exists and passwword matches
  request.session["isLoggedIn"] = True
  request.session["username"] = request.POST.get("username")
```

and

```
{% if request.session.isLoggedIn %}
{{request.session.username}}

{% else if not request.session.isLoggedIn %}
<p>User not in session or logged off</p>
{% endif %}
```

but I am confused where to put this code !?

I suppose the first code block is to be add in my studentlogin view in views.py?

Comment: Do you want to authenticate user?

Comment: Why are you not using Django's authentication backend? You can use it even with a custom user model. Also, please do not store plain text passwords in your database :)

Comment: @bichanna Yes but I am storing user data in custom database table

Comment: @GregKaleka Really , how can I use django's authentication backend with custom user model ??

Comment: There are a few ways. Here's a good blog post on some options: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```
from django.contrib import auth

user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    # do whatever you want here
else:
    # when credentials are not right...
```

Comment: This will go in models.py right ?

Comment: No. You write it in views.py